# Can I apply a macro to a struct in a Swift package?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm working on a new app which will use SwiftData. The models I want to persist are from an external package. Specifically, I want to persist `Radical`, `Kanji`, `Vocabulary`, and `KanaVocabulary` structs from the following package:

https://github.com/aaronsky/wanikani-swift/blob/main/Sources/WaniKani/Models/Subject.swift

Ideally, I'd like to do this without modifying the underlying package. Is it possible to add the `@Model` macro to these structs from within my app, or will I have to modify the package source code directly?

Comment: `protocol PersistentModel : AnyObject, …`, as you can see it needs to be a class and not a value type.